# undefined local variable or method `task_params'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Task_params isn't recognised and I'm not sure why. I've gone over it many times and still can't work it out. The part of the code throwing up the error is right at the bottom, although i've used task_params in create. I'm new to this so hopefully i'm not missing something too obvious! I'm using Ruby on Rails. Thanks.
Realised I made a really stupid mistake. I was following a tutorial that used the model task. So I shouldn't actually be using task params but the model Im using!

```
class ModuleListsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_module_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_student, only: [:new, :create]

# GET /module_lists
# GET /module_lists.json
def index
@module_lists = ModuleList.all
end

# GET /module_lists/1
# GET /module_lists/1.json
def show
end

# GET /module_lists/new
def new
  @module_list = @student.module_lists.new
end

# GET /module_lists/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /module_lists
# POST /module_lists.json
def create
  @module_list = @student.module_lists.new(task_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @module_list.save
      format.html { redirect_to @module_list, notice: 'Module successfully      created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @module_list }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @module_list.errors, status:   :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /module_lists/1
# PATCH/PUT /module_lists/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @module_list.update(module_list_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @module_list, notice: 'Module list was   successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @module_list }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @module_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /module_lists/1
# DELETE /module_lists/1.json
def destroy
  @module_list.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to module_lists_url, notice: 'Module list was   successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_module_list
    @module_list = ModuleList.find(params[:id])
  end

  def module_list_params
    params.require(:module_list).permit(:student_id, :title, :description,   :credit_value)
  end

  def set_student
    @student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id]) ||
    Student.find(task_params[:student_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you do not define `task_params` in the first place. It should work when you add something like this:

```
def task_params
  params.require(:module_list).permit(:content, :user_id)
end
```

This has to go to your `private` section, at the end of the file. And what you put between the round brackets after `permit` depends on which elements you ask the user to submit via your forms. Every element has to be permitted, otherwise it won't be stored to the database.